# Page won't fill height of browser

Tags: asp.net, html, css, web

I've just started looking into CSS3 and HTML and I wanted to use it for a University project that asked us to make an ASP.NET website, but I can't get the `height` of the content to fill the 100% of the browser... It's actually not even taking into consideration the content of the default.aspx.

Tried a bunch of stuff on other questions around here, but most times they either don't do anything or mess the whole positioning of everything.

Was hoping you guys could give me some tips on how to fix it. Here's the fiddle: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TfpF5/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the form also with `height: 100%;`. Check out this fork of your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/tushar2289/a5Bhv/1/

Comment: Wow... Yeah that did the work, thank you very much. Could I ask why form, like what's the logic behind it and what is it? Would love to know for future projects if it's not too much to ask.

Comment: The reason it didnt work before was because the div with class page has height 100% but its parent (form) is not set with any height. The way percentages work is dependant on its immediate parent. Since, there was no height mentioned for the parent its height is by default 'auto. When height is auto, the element takes the height of its content.